If $I$ is an analytic p-ideal on $\omega$ then it is $F_{\sigma \delta}$. Moreover, it is either $F_{\sigma \delta}$-complete or $F_\sigma$.
I have a question about Corollary 3.4. in page 343 in  "S. Solecki, Analytic ideals, Bull. Symbolic Logic, 2 (1996)"
https://doi.org/10.2307/420994.

If $I$ is an analytic p-ideal on $\omega$ then it is $F_{\sigma \delta}$. Moreover, it is either $F_{\sigma \delta}$-complete or $F_\sigma$.

What is the meaning of complete in "$F_{\sigma \delta}$-complete"?
Is that meaning as usual that any cauchy sequence in $I$ is convergent sequence? or does "$F_{\sigma \delta}$-complete" mean some thing else?
Also, I have a question about the proof:
Since $I$ is n analytic p-ideal on $\omega$ then it is of the form $Exh( \phi)$ for some finite lower semi continuous submeasure $ \phi$ then $I=Exh( \phi)$.
then by another teorem we know that for any finite lower semi continuous submeasure $ \phi$;  $I=Exh(\phi)$ is an $ F_{\sigma \delta}$.
So we just have to prove the moreover part. But I can't know how. Any help?
Note:
$Exh(\phi) = \{A \in 2^\omega : \lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(A \backslash n)=0 \}$
Where $A \backslash n= A\cap \{n,n+1,n+2,...\}$
